# Java - Date formatting

Tags: java, hibernate, simpledateformat

In a table I have a date object. I want to compare this date object with the current date (after 00:00). My code is:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
String dateBufferString = format.format(date);
Date dateBuffer = format.parse(dateBufferString);

System.out.println("date: " + format.format(date));
System.out.println("dateBufferSTring " + dateBufferString);
System.out.println("dateBuffer: " + dateBuffer);

studentList = session.createCriteria(Student.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("graduationDate", dateBuffer)).list();
```

The output of this is:

```
date: 2012-03-07 00:00:00
dateBufferSTring 2012-03-07 00:00:00
dateBuffer: Wed Mar 07 00:00:00 EET 2012
```

But still the studentList returns 0. What is wrong with the above code? Is there any way to format a date without converting it to a String first by using SimpleDateFormat?

Answer (score 3):

You have your `Date` object - no need to go through different formats.

Comment: but I needed to get an object and set its time to 00:00 to compare with another object.. I find the solution to this issue by using Calendar. I used Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY. Thanks for your reply anyway..